# Double access to pages

Tags: 7, users

I have a really strange problem on my Drupal site: The site reports double access to every page.

When I'm visiting an admin/something URL as administrator user, I can see in the log a warning alerting me that an anonymous user is trying to access that page.
I discovered this error when clearing the log page and a warning instantly was added telling me that a user is trying to access the page.

How can I check why this double access occurs?
This is causing me a lot of problems. (No Drupal message is shown.)

Comment: Do you have facebook or any similar module installed that would try to crawl your page after it's accessed?  For example, if you have a "like button" or other social widget installed, they will do this.

Comment: Is it always, or only for you? To me it looks like virus or antivirus trying to access pages you are visiting. But if it happens for everyone, then it's something different.

Comment: Thank you @Mołot! I think I have some kind of virus on my pc bacause logging from my office computer i have not the double access problem.
I'll test again from my pc shutting down the antivirus and I'll post an answer

Comment: It looks like you found a reason. Don't hesitate to post it as an answer, if you really did :)